# installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell, wkwebview

I have a UICollectionViewController and each of my UICollectionViewCells contains a subview WKWebView.  I am trying to implement the installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement = true so I can re-order the cells.  I have implemented the

collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,
        toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath)

But it seems the WKWebView is intercepting the long press.  How can I fix this so that it is ignored on the WKWebView so re-ording works as expected?

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WKWebView` has its own long-press recognizers which can intercept long-press gesture on the cell. 
To fix this, you can add into the cell a transparent view covering the web view. If you need to have also interaction on the web view working, you will need to implement collection view re-ordering interaction by yourself with methods:

```
- beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:
- updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition:
- endInteractiveMovement
- cancelInteractiveMovement
```

Comment: This works, but what if I also want pinch to zoom to work on the webkit view underneath?

Comment: If you implemented it currently in the first way (e.g. transparent view covering the web view), you can add your own pinch recognizer on transparent view and then change zooming scale of webView's scroll view manually. Or proceed with the second way in the answer (custom collection re-ordering implementation).

Comment: The problem is I would like most of the gestures in the WKWebView to function as normal, pinch to zoom, double tap to pop back to size to view, swipe to move around a zoomed view, etc...  It's just the long touch that needs to be sent to the collectionviewcontroller to handle reordering.  Is there any way to keep the web view in the front to handle 90% of the gestures but intercept the long press somehow?

Comment: Only by intruding into private API. You will need to catch long-press on your cell before the web-view catches it and then call method which is an action of collection view's private long-press recognizer in the cell.